# Some content types don't go through node.html.twig

Tags: theming, 8

I am using Drupal 8 RC1 and run into issue. I upgrade my site from Drupal 8 beta 15 to Drupal 8 RC1. 
For Some of my content types page don't get rendered using node.html.twig (node.html.twig not invoked). NO error message and page looks fine.
it actually rendered using blocks and fields.

Comment: Did you do a `drush cr` or clear caches via the UI?

Comment: If the page looks fine what makes you think the node template isn't invoked?

Comment: @Clive twig debug. I know it's strange but happning. It don't make me any sense but maybe it relates to as have another issue when try to configure block get error Recoverable fatal error: Object of class Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation could not be converted to string in Drupal\Component\Utility\Xss::filter() (line 72 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/Xss.php).

Comment: Pretty sure that's just render cache and by design and should have been like that before already unless you had render caching disabled. Maybe smartcache has been enabled which is using a different cache backend.

Comment: @Berdir Could you please elaborate little more... As i think it is not a caching issue.